# how to increase the speed of Angular JS coding

Tags: angularjs, performance, coding-style

I have developed a lot of system with `asp net MVC`, in this framework, I write many helpers and tools for increasing programming speed, I put `UIHint` attribute to generate my view and so on.for about 1 year our team change presentation layer and switch to `Angular JS`. Our development is much slower than `ASP MVC`. We have a lot of nesting forms and our view is really spaghetti:(. We use services, directives, and factories but it not really enough for increasing programming speed. maybe we are in mistake and we did not understand `Angular JS` correctly. Do you know how can we increase our performance?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting is point is John Papa's best practices guide for angular. Although not directly related on your question, following this set of rules will get you a huge speedup on the medium-long run.

To mention some items that pop out of my mind are:

1. defining a directive for pieces of views that appear more then once through out your application so that you can just define it once, è plug it whenever you need in the future.
2. defining a filter for any task/transformation which you see used frequently in your application, and which isn't related to any view.